# How to retrieve resposne from Expressroute authorization

Tags: python, azure

I am experimenting with Python Network mgmt class and I got to a point where I was Able to create express quote authorization but I can't figure out how to review the response here's what I am using

```
 authorizations = network_client.express_route_circuit_authorizations.create_or_update(
            resource_group_name, circuit_name, authorization_name, authorization_parameters)
```

have been all over sdk documentation but I am unable to figure out
Anybody can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of this object, and available attributes are here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2018_11_01.models.express_route_circuit_authorization_py3.expressroutecircuitauthorization?view=azure-python

Comment: Thanks Laurent,
I did follow the SDK and the object attributes, I am having hard time extracting the values from the object. 
authorizations['authrozation_key'] 
generates the following exception
Getting expressroute authorization returned an exception 'LROPoller' object is not subscriptable

Comment: You need to do a ".result()" first, to get the object. ".result()" will be a blocking call until the resource is ready. ".result()" will return the object you need. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/msrest/msrest.polling.lropoller?view=azure-python